# iText7, cannot set formField value without getting error

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I am trying to add a Field and Annotation, but when I try to set the value, I get this error `object.must.be.indirect.to.work.with.this.wrapper`. This error occurs regardless of which field is set, or where it is set, it seems. Does anyone know how to get around this error?

Here is the sample code that is causing my problem:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static final String DEST = "sampleOutput.pdf";
    public static final String SRC = "sample.pdf";
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        new HelloWorld().createPdf(SRC, DEST);
    }

    public void createPdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException {

        //Initialize PDF reader and writer
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);

        //Initialize PDF document
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);

        // Initialize document
        Document document = new Document(pdf);

        HelloWorld.addAcroForm(pdf, document);

        //Close document
        document.close();
    }

    public static PdfAcroForm addAcroForm(PdfDocument pdf, Document doc) throws IOException {
        int numPages = pdf.getNumberOfPages();
        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);

        PdfTextFormField confField = PdfFormField.createText(pdf);
        confField.setFieldName("confirmation");

        PdfSignatureFormField sigField = PdfFormField.createSignature(pdf);
        sigField.setFieldName("signature");

        PdfWidgetAnnotation firstPageConf = new PdfWidgetAnnotation(new Rectangle(0, 0, 425, 15));
        PdfWidgetAnnotation pageConf = new PdfWidgetAnnotation(new Rectangle(0, 0, 425, 15));
        PdfWidgetAnnotation signature = new PdfWidgetAnnotation(new Rectangle(0, 100, 425, 15));

        //add conf annotation based on first page or not
        for (int i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
            PdfPage page = pdf.getPage(i);

            if (i == 1) {
                page.addAnnotation(firstPageConf);
            } else {
                page.addAnnotation(pageConf);
            }
        }

        form.addField(confField);
        form.addField(sigField);        

        confField.addKid(firstPageConf);
        confField.addKid(pageConf);

        sigField.addKid(signature);   

        //this one is different because we try to set a value....
        PdfTextFormField testField = PdfFormField.createText(pdf);
        testField.setFieldName("test");
        PdfWidgetAnnotation test = new PdfWidgetAnnotation(new Rectangle(0, 100, 425, 15));
        pdf.getPage(1).addAnnotation(test);
        testField.addKid(test);
        testField.setValue("testValue");//error 'object.must.be.indirect.to.work.with.this.wrapper' occurs here

        return form;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bruno's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40406464/1729265) almost did it. But in the case at hand not only the annotation `test` but also the form field `testField` needs to be made indirect before setting the field value. Fortunately this can be achieved as a side effect of adding the field to the AcroForm which you should do anyways.

Thus, simply also add the line

```
form.addField(testField);
```

right before the `testField.setValue` call, cf. the test [AddFieldWithValue.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/form/AddFieldWithValue.java#L26), in particular the methods `testAddLineElliot` and `addAcroForm`.

Comment: Interestingly, I run into this problem again when I have two separate kids under a field: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40712084/itext7-setvalue-method-not-working

Answer (score 0):

First this: we noticed that there's a problem with the error messages in the current iText 7 version. The error you see is the *key* for the error, not the *value* of the error message. Fortunately, the key of the error message already gives us sufficient information to know what is wrong.

In PDF you have direct objects and indirect objects. A direct object is the unreferenced object as such. In this case, you have an annotation dictionary that is a direct object (the `test` object).

You are trying to add this to a field as a kid, and the error tells you: *hey, I can't deal with direct objects. I need an indirect reference to an indirect object. You are adding an object that isn't known as an indirect object yet, hence I can't add it.*

How to solve this? Well, you should make sure that `test` is added to the document as an indirect object. One way to do this, is to add it as an annotation to a page (which is what you *should* do anyway, otherwise your code doesn't make any sense).

So let's add a line:

```
PdfTextFormField testField = PdfFormField.createText(pdf);
testField.setFieldName("test");
PdfWidgetAnnotation test = new PdfWidgetAnnotation(new Rectangle(0, 0, 425, 15));
pdf.getPage(1).addAnnotation(test);
testField.addKid(test);
testField.setValue("testValue");
```

By adding the line:

```
pdf.getPage(1).addAnnotation(test);
```

We add the annotation dictionary to the PDF as an indirect object. A reference is created. That reference is used when you use the `addKid()` method.

Comment: I added the pdf.getPage(1).addAnnotation(test); line but I still get the same error.

Comment: That's strange. I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I must be doing something silly elsewhere. I added more context if you can take a look. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This error occurs when I setValue for any PdfFormField in the code above