# iText7 setValue method not working

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I am trying to add a form to a pdf using `iText 7`.

I keep getting an error when trying to set the value of the field. I haven't been able to find information from the [documentation](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.1/) of the `addKid()` method. Does anyone know how to get around this error?

Here's a sample of the code I'm using:

```
PdfTextFormField confField = PdfFormField.createText(pdf);
confField.setFieldName(fieldName);

PdfWidgetAnnotation confCoverAnnot = new PdfWidgetAnnotation(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
PdfWidgetAnnotation confAnnot = new PdfWidgetAnnotation(new Rectangle(x2, y2, width2, height2));

for (int i = 1; i<= numPages; i++) {
    switch(i) {
        case 1:
            pdf.getPage(i).addAnnotation(confCoverAnnot);
            break;
        default:
            pdf.getPage(i).addAnnotation(confAnnot);
            break;
    }
}


/*
    Trying to have two different annotations reference the same field value.

    Upon using the `setValue()` method, I get: object.must.be.indirect.to.work.with.this.wrapper
    Any way to get this to work properly?
*/
form.addField(confField);
confField.addKid(confCoverAnnot);
confField.addKid(confAnnot);
if (value.equals("") != true) {
    confField.setValue(value); //error here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume the error you are getting is this `PdfException`: Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Object must be indirect to work with this wrapper`?

The solution is to mark you annotations as indirect after creating them:

```
PdfWidgetAnnotation confCoverAnnot = new PdfWidgetAnnotation(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
confCoverAnnot.makeIndirect(pdf);
PdfWidgetAnnotation confAnnot = new PdfWidgetAnnotation(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
confAnnot.makeIndirect(pdf);
```

Explanation:
When setting the values of form fields in iText7, it expects the annotations to be indirect objects and will raise an exception when they aren't. Since `PdfWidgetAnnotation`is created independently from  the `PdfDocument`, the link needs to be specified explicitly by calling `makeIndirect()`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Makes sense now :)